# Example of non-rectifiable curve with finite arc length integral

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, arc-length

If $y=f(x)$ is a real valued function for $x\in[0,1]$ is the graph of a rectifiable curve, then the integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$ converges and is said to be it's arc length. According to my professor, the convergence of this integral does not imply that the curve is rectifiable. I am hoping someone can give an example of a curve $f$ for which this integral is finite, and $f$ is not rectifiable.

Now, I know that any $C^1$ curve is rectifiable, so in a counterexample, I would initially expect the given integral to be improper and so probably some bad behavior occurs at the endpoint, like with $\sin(1/(\pi x))$. Then we can find a sequence of points $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, \cdots$ where $(f(x_2)-f(x_1)) + (f(x_4) - f(x_3)) + \cdots$ is infinite. But, if this sum is infinite then it looks like the integral is infinite as well since 
$$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(x)dx < \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$$
and adding this up a bunch will give something more than infinity.

So that idea is toast. Somehow we need to come up with a curve that is not rectifiable for another reason, like it's derivative exists but is everywhere discontinuous or something strange. Any ideas?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3072835/72031) for a thorough presentation on arc-length. For your question *if $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a, b]$ and $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ then the curve $y=f(x) $ is rectifiable and its arc-length is given by the integral in question*. However a rectifiable curve does not imply the existence of the integral (like $f$ may not be differentiable). In my linked answer you can see the necessary and sufficient conditions for a curve to be rectifiable.

Comment: In short the example you seek _does not exist_.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I interpreted the question as allowing, for example, a function $f$ that is continuous and differentiable almost everywhere on $[0, 1],$ with $f'$ bounded, so that the proper Riemann integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$ exists, by Lebesgue's criterion. The [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is monotonic, so its graph is rectifiable. According to the Wikipedia article, the graph has length $2$; but the value of the integral is $1,$ because the derivative is zero where it exists. Perhaps there's a nastier example where the graph isn't rectifiable?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: The integral in your comment exists as Lebesgue integral. For the existence of Riemann integral you need continuity (and not just the existence) of $f'$ almost everywhere. The way this integral is related to arc-length is via mean value theorem and Riemann sums. I don't know if the arc-length can be related to a Lebesgue integral (which does not exist as a Riemann integral).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for the correction. I initially forgot to mention boundedness, too, but I managed to edit my comment before posting it to include that, and must have been so relieved to have caught an error in time that I made another equally bad one! It is only necessary to replace the words "continuous and differentiable almost everywhere" with "continuously differentiable almost everywhere" - is that correct? (I've just got out of bed, so I could still be confused!)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: yes if $f$ is continuously differentiable with bounded derivative then the integral makes sense. However I think that the arc-length can be expressed as an integral only under some conditions. One set of conditions is that $f'$ exists in whole interval, is bounded and $\sqrt{1+f'^2}$ is Riemann integrable. I don't know if these conditions can be relaxed and yet the arc-length can be expressed as an integral. Thus in general one should not expect the implication "integral in question exists therefore it represents arc-length" to be true.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I was about to start typing up the proof that the arc length of $\phi^*$ is $h + |k|$ (it's unexpectedly easy), but I can't proceed, because of a sick and guilty feeling that the Riemann integral expression for the arc length makes no sense! I think I was unconsciously taking it for granted that a function equal a.e. to a Riemann integrable function is itself Riemann integrable. But that is false, so one cannot give meaning to the Riemann integral of a function that is *undefined* on a null set. I think I shall have to appoint you as the voice of my mathematical conscience! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work, but it will take some time to write out a full proof.
(See the update below.)

Let $\phi \colon [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

For real $a, b, k,$ and $h > 0,$ consider this function ($[b, b + k]$ means $[b + k, b]$ if $k < 0$):
$$
\phi^* = \Phi(a, h, b, k) \colon [a, a + h] \to [b, b + k], \ x \mapsto b + k\phi\left(\frac{x - a}h\right).
$$
I will take for granted, without proof for the moment, that $\phi^*$ is differentiable almost everywhere, with derivative zero where it is defined (this follows from well-known properties of $\phi,$ and so it needn't be proved here) and (I expect this to be not too hard to prove, perhaps by expressing $\phi^*$ as a uniform limit of "step-like" functions based on approximations to the Cantor set) the graph of $\phi^*$ is rectifiable, with arc length $h + |k|.$ (According to the Wikipedia article, this is known to be true when $h = k.$ It is intuitively quite clear why this is so, and the proof ought to generalise to the case of distinct $h, k.$)

For $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots,$ let $s_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ partial sum of the series:
$$
1 - \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 + \cdots = \log2.
$$

Construct a continuous function $f \colon [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ by glueing together these functions, for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$:
\begin{align*}
\Phi\left(1 - \frac1{2^{2k}}, \frac1{2^{2k+1}}, s_{2k}, \frac1{2k+1}\right) & \colon
\left[1 - \frac1{2^{2k}}, 1 - \frac1{2^{2k+1}}\right] \to [s_{2k}, s_{2k+1}], \\
\Phi\left(1 - \frac1{2^{2k+1}}, \frac1{2^{2k+2}}, s_{2k+1}, -\frac1{2k+2}\right) & \colon \left[1 - \frac1{2^{2k+1}}, 1 - \frac1{2^{2k+2}}\right] \to [s_{2k+2}, s_{2k+1}],
\end{align*}
where:
\begin{gather*}
f\left(1 - \frac1{2^{n}}\right) = s_n \quad (n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots), \\
f(1) = \log2.
\end{gather*}

Then $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere, with derivative zero wherever it is defined, therefore:

<sup>[As Paramanand Singh pointed out in the comments, and as I've only slowly come to understand, the expression on the left cannot be understood as a Riemann integral, therefore my answer does not strictly meet the terms of the question. (See the second update, below.)]</sup>
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}\,dx = 1.
$$
But for $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$ the graph of the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[0, 1 - 2^{-n}]$ has arc length:
$$
1 - \frac1{2^n} + \left(1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \cdots + \frac1n\right)
$$
and this is unbounded, therefore the graph of $f$ is not rectifiable.

### Update

It turns out to be remarkably easy to prove that the arc length of the graph of $\phi^*$ is $h + |k|.$

@user856's beautifully simple answer to [Arc length of the Cantor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27859) says everything that is really needed, but it can be misunderstood, as can be seen from one of the comments on it. The same reservation applies to Dustan Levenstein's brief comment on [Elementary ways to calculate the arc length of the Cantor function (and singular function in general)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889066), which I believe is a version of the same argument. In the hope of being easily understood, I will labour the proof. I'm sorry!

For $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots,$ the $n^\text{th}$ stage of the traditional "middle third" construction of the Cantor set yields $m = 2^n - 1$ pairwise disjoint open intervals, the smallest of which have length $\left(\frac13\right)^n,$ and whose lengths sum to $1 - \left(\frac23\right)^n.$ Given $\epsilon > 0$ with $\epsilon < 2h,$ take $n$ large enough that $\left(\frac23\right)^n < \frac{\epsilon}{2h}.$
Arrange the open intervals in ascending order as $J_1, J_2, \ldots, J_m.$

Set $q_0 = 0, p_m = 1.$ In $J_i,$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m,$ take a closed subinterval $[p_{i-1}, q_i],$ where:
$$
q_i - p_{i-1} \geqslant \left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2h}\right)|J_i|.
$$

Construct a polygonal chain $Q_0P_0Q_1P_1\cdots Q_mP_m$ of points on the graph of $\phi^*,$ where:
$$
P_i = (a + hp_i, b + k\phi(p_i)),\quad Q_i = (a + hq_i, b + k\phi(q_i)) \qquad (i = 0, 1, \ldots, m).
$$
Because $\phi$ is constant on each of $J_1, J_2, \ldots, J_m,$ and because in particular $\phi(p_{i-1}) = \phi(q_i)$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m,$ the length of the chain is:
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{={}} \sum_{i=1}^m\|P_{i-1}Q_i\| + \sum_{i=0}^m\|Q_iP_i\| \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^mh(q_i-p_{i-1}) + \sum_{i=0}^m\sqrt{h^2(p_i-q_i)^2 + k^2(\phi(p_i)-\phi(q_i))^2} \\
& > h\sum_{i=1}^m(q_i-p_{i-1}) + |k|\sum_{i=0}^m (\phi(p_i)-\phi(q_i)) \\
& > h\left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2h}\right)\sum_{i=1}^m|J_i| + |k|(\phi(p_m) - \phi(q_0)) \\
& > h\left(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2h}\right)^2 + |k|(\phi(1) - \phi(0)) \\
& > h + |k| - \epsilon.
\end{align*}

I hope it will be clear from the Triangle Inequality - without me labouring the details in the same way - that the length of *any* chain $Q_0R_1R_2\cdots R_lP_m$ of successive points on the graph of $\phi^*$ is at most $h + |k|.$

It follows that the arc length of the graph of $\phi^*,$ defined as the least upper bound of the lengths of all such chains, is well-defined and is equal to $h + |k|.$

### Second update

I'll try to explain in gory detail what has been confusing me so much,
to reduce the risk of confusing others! The function
$g(x) = \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}$ is defined, and has the constant value
$1,$ on an open set $E \subset [0, 1],$ whose complement (a union of
countably many scaled, translated copies of the Cantor set) has
measure $0.$ Therefore, any extension of $g$ to the whole of
$[0, 1]$ is Riemann integrable, and the value of any such integral
is $1.$ It does *not* follow that $g$ itself is Riemann
integrable on $[0, 1]!$ There is simply no definition of the Riemann
integral that applies here.

As far as I can tell, the best that can be done using the Riemann
integral is to apply e.g. section 11.2 of Vladimir A. Zorich,
*Mathematical Analysis II* (first edition 2004), according to which
$E$ is an "admissible set", and:
$$
\int_E\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}\,dx= 1.
$$
This is a proper Riemann integral (Zorich also gives a definition of
an improper Riemann integral, which adds nothing here), but I find
this little consolation.

Comment: Very clever observation with the Cantor function! Thanks for the neat solution

Comment: You're welcome. It was fun. I'll try to get round to completing the proof some time. I'd be interested to know what example your professor had in mind. If you find out, do post it as an answer.

Comment: See related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889066/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's great - it should save me a lot of work, which I wasn't entirely looking forward to! I'd better read carefully through all those proofs, to make sure that at least one of them applies to the modified version of the Cantor function that I used. (But first, breakfast!) Incidentally, I Googled for references to "Cantor function" and "arc length" ... ah, no, I didn't! I Googled for "Cantor *curve*" and "arc length", and that's how I failed to find that MSE article myself.

Comment: My own search capabilities are limited. I think I got this by luck. Compared to the treasure stored on MSE, I think its search feature is just not upto the mark and getting something out of thus treasure is pain (sometimes).